# How should I implement collision handling in my 2D game? (Kivy in Python)

Tags: python, kivy, game-physics

I would like to implement a collision logic for a head soccer type game. I have a Ball and a Player class and would like them to interact seemlessly by using physics simulation.

I have tried calculating forces in vector and applying them to my code but I never seemed to get it right. Whenever I implemented something, the ball didn't interact well with the player when they collided horizontaly and the ball somehow got sucked into the player rectangle. Below is my current code without any collision logic:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Ball(Widget):
velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)
gravity = 0.2
bounce_factor = 0.7
mass = 1.0
max_velocity = 10

    def move(self):
        self.velocity_y -= self.gravity
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos
    
        # Check if the ball is on the ground
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y = 0
            self.velocity_y *= -self.bounce_factor
    
        # Avoid negative velocities due to bounce
        if self.velocity_y < 0 and self.y == 0:
            self.velocity_y = 0
    
        # Set a maximum velocity
        if self.velocity_y > self.max_velocity:
            self.velocity_y = self.max_velocity
        if self.velocity_x > self.max_velocity:
            self.velocity_x = self.max_velocity

class Player(Widget):
velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)
jump_strength = 15
gravity = 0.5
speed = 10
mass = 2.0

    def move(self):
        self.velocity_y -= self.gravity
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos
    
        # Ensure the player doesn't fall below the screen
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y = 0

class GameScreen(Widget):
ball = ObjectProperty(None)
player = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down, on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_up)
    
    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down, on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_up)
        self._keyboard = None
    
    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'd':
            self.player.velocity_x = self.player.speed
        elif keycode[1] == 'a':
            self.player.velocity_x = -self.player.speed
        elif keycode[1] == 'spacebar':
            self.player.velocity_y = self.player.jump_strength
        return True
    
    def _on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        if keycode[1] == 'a' and self.player.velocity_x < 0:
            self.player.velocity_x = 0
        elif keycode[1] == 'd' and self.player.velocity_x > 0:
            self.player.velocity_x = 0
        return True
    
    def serve_ball(self):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(0, -1)
    
    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        self.player.move()
    
        if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1
    
        if (self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.right > self.width):
            self.ball.velocity_x *= -1
    
        if self.player.top >= self.height:
            self.player.velocity_y *= 0
            self.player.y = self.height - self.player.height
    
        if self.player.x < 0:
            self.player.velocity_x *= 0
            self.player.x = 0
    
        if self.player.right > self.width:
            self.player.velocity_x *= 0
            self.player.x = self.width - self.player.width

class SoccerApp(App):
def build(self):
game = GameScreen()
game.serve_ball()
Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
SoccerApp().run()
```

Here is the corresponding .kv file:

```
<Ball>:
size: 25, 25
canvas:
Ellipse:
pos: self.pos
size: self.size

<Player>:
size: 50, 50
canvas:
Rectangle:
pos: self.pos
size: self.size

<GameScreen>:
ball: game_ball
player: game_player

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 2 - 30
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
    
    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 2 / 4 + 30
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
    
    Ball:
        id: game_ball
        center: self.parent.center
    
    Player:
        id: game_player
        center_x: root.width * 1 / 4
        center_y: root.height * 1/6
```

Comment: in `PyGame` you can often see method: first calculate position only on X, next check collisions with all objects and eventually move it little back (so it only touch but not overlap), next get original position and calculate position only on Y and check again collisions with all objects. And finally move object in new calculated position

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the `collide_widget()` method of `Widget` to determine if there is a collision. Then use some logic to determine which way the bounce should go. Here as an example of a method that could be added to the `Ball` class and called in your `update()` method:

```
def check_collision(self, player):
    if self.collide_widget(player):
        if self.y <= player.top and self.center_y > player.top and self.center_x < player.right and self.center_x > player.x:
            # bounce off top of player
            self.velocity_y *= -self.bounce_factor
            self.y = player.top
        elif self.top >= player.y and self.center_y < player.y and self.center_x < player.right and self.center_x > player.x:
            # bounce off bottom of player
            self.velocity_y *= -self.bounce_factor
            self.top = player.y
        elif self.x <= player.right and self.center_x > player.right and self.center_y < player.top and self.center_y > player.y:
            # bounce off right side of player
            self.velocity_x *= -self.bounce_factor
            self.x = player.right
        elif self.right >= player.x and self.center_x < player.x and self.center_y < player.top and self.center_y > player.y:
            # bounce off left side of player
            self.velocity_x *= -self.bounce_factor
            self.right = player.x
        else:
            print('\tdid not calulate collision:')
            print('\t\tball:', self.pos, self.center, self.top, self.right)
            print('\t\tplayer:', player.pos, player.center, player.top, player.right)
```

This code has not been extensively tested, so expect modifications to be required.